# Is there a library to read JSON in C# on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, json, compact-framework, json.net

I am trying to find a library to parse JSON on C# on Windows Mobile (working with Visual Studio 2005). The libraries that I have found that allow me to parse JSON in C# (litjson and Jayrock) don't work on Windows Mobile, they require classes that are not present in the .NET compact framework. Is there any library that I have overlooked? Or is there another easy way to parse JSON given these circumstances?

Answer (score 13):

[Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) supports the .NET 3.5 compact framework.

Comment: , i am using Json.NET and downloaded the dll and saved to my Desktop folder added the reference.It shows there is not enough space on the disk

Comment: @shanavascet I've the same problem how did you get around?

Comment: @JoeB I had been adding the wrong reference. you can see a CE version in the dll folder. You should add the compact version for windows mobile.

Comment: @shanavascet Thanks for replying But I don't see and CE dll please advice

Comment: @shanavascet  I got the right version from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295872/json-net-windows-mobile-error-when-serializing) Thanks anyway

Comment: It doesn't add the CE dll

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at what the "missing" classes actually have to do for the existing libraries? If they're reasonably simple to implement yourself, that would be my first suggestion - then contribute the results back to those projects.

Answer (score 1):

look [here](http://json.org/)- several C# json libraries to pick from. also, "manually" parsing JSON from string is not all that difficult.