# Json Reader for window phone 7?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, windows-phone-7

Is there a json library for c# that will work with windows phone 7 just read the data without serialising without using a datacontract.

I found fastJSON but that didn't work because it used reflection.

I don't want to serialize into an object just iterate through the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://json.codeplex.com/ JSON.NET would work well

Comment: thanks i've been using this, but i could only find how to serialise. how do I walk through the json without creating any c# classes?

Comment: @Joseph it has a LINQ provider for manually reading/writing it apparently.

Comment: Use JObject.SelectToken to easily browse through your JSON string. It is in the LINQ namespace (Newtonsoft.JSON.Linq).

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here:

[Is there a library to read JSON in C# on Windows Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183473/is-there-a-library-to-read-json-in-c-on-windows-mobile)

That says [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) supports the Compact Framework 3.5.  Silverlight uses the compact framework so this *might* be compatible.  Either way, Googling doesn't yield much so it might be your closest match.

Comment: Thats for windows mobile 6.5, this is for windows phone 7. There's a big difference.

Comment: @TJHeuvel The question?  Yes I'm aware of that, but the use of the Compact Framework tends to impose limitations that are similar amongst versions.  If it doesn't already support it, it is closer than most in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, JSON.NET does the job very well. But why bother with the extra work, when you can use a library build on top of JSON.NET.

[RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) will make your life even easier. And it got automatic matching of properties, and many other fancy stuff, so you avoid having to add attributes everywhere.