# JSON .Net Windows Mobile Error when serializing

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, windows-mobile-6

I am running this bit of code:

```
 string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(somethingToSend);
```

And it throws this exception:

> MissingMethodException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC'.

Here is my configuration:

- Visual Studio 2008 (with all the latest service packs etc)
- Smart Device project targeting Windows Mobile 6 .Net 3.5
- [Json DotNet](http://json.codeplex.com/) version 4.5 Release 7 (referencing the DLL from the WindowsPhone folder in the zip)

The answer to this question "[Is there a library to read JSON in C# on Windows Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183473/1039947)" implies that it should work.

I am running it in debug with the real device attached (so no emulator) where I have previously installed the CAB file from here without error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\NETCFv35.wce.armv4.cab

The application runs fine until I click the button that is running the line above, so does anyone know what I am missing?

This thread "[Json.Compact.dll for Windows CE 5.0?](http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/228200)" suggests that I would need the Windows SDK installed, which I have.  Given it is running on the device itself I guess that is not going to be the fix anyway.

The other suggestion is to build from source but like the author of the question I cannot load the project file into VS 2008 to do that.  I could create a new project and include the source files and try to get it to compile but before I do that I thought I would ask here if it is worth it or if there is something else missing from the installation on the device perhaps?  Or maybe I should be using an alternate build?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I needed to RTFM!  The readme file says:

> Microsoft stopped support for the Compact Framework in Visual Studio 2010.
>   For a Compact Framework 3.5 build download Json.NET 3.5.

So I grabbed the most recent 3.5 version which is: [Json.NET 3.5 Release 8](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/3.5.8), updated my reference to point to the `Newtonsoft.Json.Compact.dll` assembly, ran it and it worked fine.

Comment: Additionally it appears that 3.5.8 found on codeplex at http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/50552  is not the same as 3.5.8 found on nuget at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/3.5.8

Comment: Link is broken.