# configure json calls from wince 5.0 app in c#.net, compact framework application

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, compact-framework, windows-ce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a library to read JSON in C# on Windows Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183473/is-there-a-library-to-read-json-in-c-sharp-on-windows-mobile)

we have a web application working in cakephp. now we need to get data from it and display on a wince device. also we want to update/send dat to the website.
For this client have selected json as the method for communication.
but, now we are having issues with getting started in visual studio to call the website using json requests and fetch data.
can you help with this? 
i will need details of dll to use and basic example of a json request to the server.
any help in this matter will be be great.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pls have a look at the following links

Consume JSON web service from .NET Compact Framework 3.5 on Windows Mobile 6
http://community.psion.com/knowledge/w/knowledgebase/1378.consume-json-web-service-from-net-compact-framework-3-5-on-windows-mobile-6.aspx

Prepare a JSON Web Service and access it with JQuery
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37727/Prepare-a-JSON-Web-Service-and-access-it-with-JQue

**Edit :**
Codetitans have written JSon Parser for diff .net flavors including CF 
http://codetitans.codeplex.com/releases/view/52555

Also check other releases in the same page (in "other downloads") for updates..

or

You can write your  own JSON parser as shown here .. Sample Implementation is there too.
http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/618/news/view/14605/14863/How-do-I-write-my-own-parser-for-JSON.html

Also this SO question
[Is there a library to read JSON in C# on Windows Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183473/is-there-a-library-to-read-json-in-c-sharp-on-windows-mobile)

Comment: hi Amitad,
thanks for the reply.
i have to work specifically with win ce 5.0 and contact framework 2.0.

JSON.Net works with 3.5 and i won't be able to use that. is there any other method of using json on 2.0 compact framework?
thanks

Comment: yep you can write your own parser as shown here http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/618/news/view/14605/14863/How-do-I-write-my-own-parser-for-JSON.html  and Codetitans have written JSon Parser for diff .net flavors including CF http://codetitans.codeplex.com/releases/view/52555 . Might need to verify them