# Can i serialize json in c# wince? Or any other option than xml serializer

Tags: serialization

i have used XML serializer in C# Windows CE application to serialize some List. The size of list can vary between 200 to 300 objects in the list. The object is not big its has 5 properties. When serializing it look fine but when deserializing is kind of slow in Window CE 5.0 environment. I have researched to look for better serializer and come up with JSON. I guess json serializer would be useful if its available in Windows CE i would like to know performance if its there and someone used it. Any other option other than JSON in wince environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Json.Net, available on Nuget, or at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

I have found the performance to vastly outstrip the .net framework serializers, so much so the templates included in later / current version of Visual Studio 2013 for asp.net applications use json.net by default.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I am working with  Window CE 5.0 with visual studio 2008 Apologize if question is not clear enough.

Comment: @coda ouch I feel your pain :-). json.net used to support the .net 3.5 compact framework as per json.net's author's comment on <http://stackoverflow.com/a/1083392/1422377> this post. It might be easy enough to pull an older release from github/codeplex for support.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess i have to develop something on my own.