# MissingMethodException was unhandled. Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.json'

Tags: c#, json, windows-ce

I am developing an project for Windows CE 5.0 using .Net 2.0 Compact.
I am developing on using MS Visual Studio 2008.

All went good until I had to work with JSON. I tried to use the [newtonsoft.json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library but when calling a function from it i get this error:

```
  Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' from assembly 
'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30AD4FE6B2A6AEED'.
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that Json.NET works on .NET 2.0 compact?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183473/is-there-a-library-to-read-json-in-c-sharp-on-windows-mobile It seems to support .NET 3.5 compact.

Comment: What's the exact filename of the `Json.NET` dll you added?

Comment: http://jsoncf.codeplex.com/ Maybe this works

Comment: Andy the file name is "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" and its the one for .Net 2.0

Comment: @HellOfACode but you are using the *Compact* Framework, not the full .NET 2.0 ... ? If the zip you downloaded doesn't contain assemblies for the Compact framework, you should find an older release that does

Comment: It's in the readme.txt, `For a Compact Framework 3.5 and Silverlight 3.0 builds download Json.NET 3.5`. The last 3.5 version was 3.5 Release 8